# TabLayout color of selected tab underline

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I change the color of the underline of the selected tab on the new [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)? 
The [PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html) has a method `setTabIndicatorColor(int color)`, `TabLayout` doesn't seem to have such a method.

[image]

Comment: have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Use `app:tabIndicatorColor`.

**Example:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Make sure you have this `namespace`: `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

**Documentation:** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#attr_android.support.design:tabIndicatorColor.

Comment: "app:tabIndicatorColor" works.But I do not find  the official docs mention it.

Comment: Yes but I rather use this than a third party library.

Comment: There is a lot of un documented things when it comes to Android development.

Comment: how can we do this in java?

Comment: @SyedRazaMehdi http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(int)

Comment: Many many thanks! You saved my day :) By default it uses `colorAccent` and it was so annoying making it white

Answer (score 4):

Try to download below file from this location :

https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget

```
SlidingTabLayout.java
SlidingTabStrip.java
```

Try to set tab indicator color this way :

```
slidingTabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
     @Override
     public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
        return getResources().getColor(R.color.color_name);
     }
});
```

Comment: He is using: android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout. Read here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html.

Comment: how to se the color of the unselected tab

Answer (score 1):

**you can use setcustomTebColorizer** 
below is the example

```
mSlidingTabLayout=(SlidingTabLayout)findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return Color.YELLOW;
            }

                @Override
                public int getDividerColor(int position) {
                    return 0;
                }
            });
```

Comment: He is using: android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout. Read here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html.

Comment: how can i remove the underline?

Comment: @alexmike Try setting the color to be the same as the tab